# Desafio em python. Dúvida

Tags: python

O desafio: receber uma string s  e um numero inteiro k, então deve separar a string em sub-strings de comprimento s/k e por fim retirar as letras repetidas em cada sub-strings. Segue o código:

```
def merge_the_tools(string,k):
n=len(string)
merge= n//k
separador=[]
lista=[]
for i in range(merge):
    start= int(i*n/merge)
    end= int((i+1)*n/merge)
    separador.append(string[start:end])
for i in range(len(separador)):
    lista.append(list(separador[i]))
return lista


aux=[]
result=merge_the_tools('AABCAAADA', 3)

for i in range(len(result)):
    aux.append(list(set(result[i])))
    print(aux[i])
```

Porém na hora de imprimir a saída tenho que ter a seguinte resposta:

```
AB
CA
AD
```

E o que eu tenho é uma resposta invertida quando uso o set():

```
BA
AC
DA
```

não consigo entender o motivo disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você verificar a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) verá que diz:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

Tradução livre:

> Um objeto `set` (conjunto) é uma coleção não-ordenada de objetos *"hasheable"* distintos.

Assim como os [conjuntos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto) que estudamos na matemática, um conjunto é um grupo de elementos onde sua ordem e repetição de elemento não é relevante.

Se você acessar a [Wiki sobre o conceito de conjuntos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Conjunto&oldid=56125742) verá que o conjunto `A = {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2}` é equivalente ao conjunto `A = {1, 2, 3}`. E isso se reflete python também:

```
a = {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2}
b = {1, 2, 3}

a == b
# True

a
# {1, 2, 3}
b
# {1, 2, 3}
```

Se você precisa que a ordem seja mantida no seu código, você de usar uma sequência, que é uma coleção onde a ordem importa. Por exemplo: listas e tuplas.

***PS***: Há um tempo li em algum lugar que a implementação de `set`s do CPython é uma "modificação" da implementação de `dict`, ou seja, sets seriam como dicionários sem valores, apenas as chaves. Confesso que, apesar de ter confirmado a afirmação após ter verificado o código fonte na época, não consigo mais achar esta referência. Porém é relevante deixar aqui a informação de que a partir do Python 3.7 a implementação de `dict` do CPython mantém a ordem de inserção das chaves do dicionário ([veja no change log](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html)) então esta informação pode não ser mais verdadeira.